# Angular 8 routing VS ngif router-outlet best practice

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

This is more of a best practice question,
a bit of context (simplified): I have a SPA with a login page, a dashboard, a 404 page and an unauthorized page.

the dashboard has a topbar and a sidebar (we will call it shell). the login page should not include the shell. The 404 and unauthorized pages should include the shell part If the user is logged in, and should not include it if the user is not logged in.

> Method A:
>   **Have a shell.module**

- will include:

  - shell-routing-module (with all the dashboard as a child route)

    - shell route will have an AuthGuard
  - shell component (with a `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` to host the dashboard, 404 and unauthorized pages)

> Method B:
>   ***ngIf router-outlet**

- no shell component
- everything will be controlled from the app-component

tl;dr app-component.html

```
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #notauthenticated>...</ng-template>
    <ng-template #authenticated>...</ng-template>
```

> Verdict:

Online i found solutions using both methods. I also implemented both, and have a few issues with each (different in each case), I think I prefer methodA, but this is my first time using angular so I am not comfortable choosing one.

Comment: You could consider https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-multiple-outlets/

Personally I use a wrapper for a part of app that needs header and footer (any but login page) and use for that a dedicated `i` segment path that is unnoticeable and sort of gathering all internal routes

Comment: @Sergey a wrapper meaning the methodA, which i named shell? :D

Comment: A wrapper meaning `wrapper.component.ts` with its own router-outlet. And in routes it has children routes all the ones that need header and footer

Comment: @Sergey i still think we mean the same thing, but i may not be communicating it correctly ;p

Comment: Using *ngIf in that kind of scenario has a bit of code smell IMO and I haven't seen it used like that with an application that has a lot of routes. I'm sure it's fine with a very small app though. I think you'll have an easier time maintaining a standard routing solution, with the 'shell' (or wrapper) as you call it.